# Decode file names from MIME messages with LotusScript

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I am parsing a MIME mail with LotusScript to get all attachments. But I get issues when it comes to encoded file names in the header. I got one file with the name

"HE336 =?Windows-1251?Q?=CF=E0=EA=E5=F2_=E4=EE=EA=F3=EC=E5=ED=F2=EE=E2.pdf?="

Is there any way to decode it with LotusScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string I get is RFC 2047 header encoding. I found that Notes supports it in MIME headers. The issue I had is when I used MIMEHeader.GetParamVal it always returns the encoded value. However MIMEHeader.GetHeaderVal and GetHeaderValAndParams has an extra parameter

```
boolean decoded

true decodes any RFC-2047 encodings
false (default) retains any encodings; false is enforced if folded is true
```

When this is set to true, I get a decoded value.

Answer (score 0):

it's been a while but I once used Julian Robichaux's Base64 classes with Jave and/or LS. You should be able to achieve what you are looking for with these.

[Base64Encoding](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/NotesTips.htm#lsencryption)

Hope that helps.

Best wishes - Michael

Comment: I tired this before, this function is very basic. If you look at the string I posted it contains a plain text in the beginning, then it opens with =?Windows-1251? charset indicator and encoded characters in that charset (not UTF8) follow. This function is unable to cope with these things.

BTW nice to see you on StackOverflow, Michael :)

Comment: It's not base64.  The ?Q? indicates that it is quoted-printable encoding.